# Classdefnotfound exception while using bean.xml in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@fb509a:
>   startup date [Fri Jul 17 21:34:24 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
>     at mySimpleSpringApp.myApp.main(myApp.java:14) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.core.OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 7 more

my main class ::

```
 package mySimpleSpringApp;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

    public class myApp {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");

            Fruit f = appContext.getBean("fruit", Fruit.class);
            Vegetable v = (Vegetable)appContext.getBean("vegetable");

            System.out.println(f.talkAboutYourself());
            System.out.println(v.talkAboutYourself());

        }

    }
```

bean xml file :: appContext.xml::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="fruit" class="mySimpleSpringApp.Fruit"></bean>
<bean id="vegetable" class="mySimpleSpringApp.Vegetable" />

</beans>
```

What i am doing wrong here?

This question might be duplicate but i did not get answer from other post, as those solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown by JVM at runtime when it try to load a class that is not present in the classpath.

Check if the class in present in the classpath or not.

May be a jar is not added in the right position or it is not correctly referenced in the classpath, or the jar version is not the right one.

**Note** the `OrderSourceProvider` is present since spring 4.1. Check if the jar loaded at runtime is older than that version.

Comment: No ,,  actually, i am watching a video and learning from there. what he does, i do same, but in my instance it is throwing error.

Comment: Who said that videos are correct or that you do exactly the same things? Perhaps that the video hides a passage or that the jars are downloaded manually from different sites or in different moments. So they can be different

Comment: If you find this answer useful you can upvote it and check is a the right answer with the green check. Thank you