# spring-dependency-injection example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm developing this example in spring about dependency injection.
When I do debug, the application launches this Exception as reported below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.(GenericApplicationContext.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:82)
>     at
>   com.journaldev.spring.di.test.ClientApplication.main(ClientApplication.java:16)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.core.OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 4 more

This is my main class:

```
public class ClientApplication {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( DIConfiguration.class );
        MyApplication app = context.getBean( MyApplication.class );
        app.processMessage( "message example", "mailtest@gmail.com" );
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Stacktrace report an exception in the row when I define *`AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`* context ( in the code is reported as row number 16 ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this issue.
[Classdefnotfound exception while using bean.xml in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480234/classdefnotfound-exception-while-using-bean-xml-in-spring)

Check your build configuration to make sure all Spring dependencies are 4.1 or greater.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem is solved; I have updated all dependencies to 4.3.0 release and the application is started.

Comment: You can also mark this answer as the best answer. It would help others who may have the same issue.